# vlc 3.0.11 is not working properly, video stuck

Tags: video, vlc, ffmpeg, vlan

hp pavilion laptop, when I play a video on vlc media player video stuck specially when I try to forward or backward the video, while other media player like mpv media player working well.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS